# Intuition for fractions of the localization of a non integral domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Consider the localization of $R = \mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$ at $6$. We use the multiplicative subset $S = \{ 1, 6 \}$. we build fractions of the form $r/s$ with $r\in R, s \in S$, with the equivalence relation: $r/s \sim r'/s' $ iff there exists an $\alpha \in S$ such that $\alpha (rs' - r's) = 0$.

Crunching the equivalence relations, we find:

```
ring: Ring of integers modulo 10
localizing at s0=6 | S = [1, 6]
===Equivalence classes===
((0, 1), set([(0, 1), (5, 6), (5, 1), (0, 6)]))
((8, 1), set([(8, 1), (8, 6), (3, 1), (3, 6)]))
((2, 1), set([(7, 6), (2, 6), (2, 1), (7, 1)]))
((4, 1), set([(4, 1), (9, 6), (4, 6), (9, 1)]))
((6, 1), set([(6, 1), (1, 6), (1, 1), (6, 6)]))
****0/1****
    -  0/ 1 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 0* 1 -  1* 0) *  1 = ( 0 -  0) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
    -  5/ 6 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 0* 6 -  1* 5) *  6 = ( 0 -  5) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
    -  5/ 1 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 0* 1 -  1* 5) *  6 = ( 0 -  5) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
    -  0/ 6 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 0* 6 -  1* 0) *  1 = ( 0 -  0) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
****8/1****
    -  8/ 1 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 8* 1 -  1* 8) *  1 = ( 8 -  8) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
    -  8/ 6 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 8* 6 -  1* 8) *  1 = ( 8 -  8) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
    -  3/ 1 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 8* 1 -  1* 3) *  6 = ( 8 -  3) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
    -  3/ 6 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 8* 6 -  1* 3) *  6 = ( 8 -  3) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
****2/1****
    -  7/ 6 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 2* 6 -  1* 7) *  6 = ( 2 -  7) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
    -  2/ 6 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 2* 6 -  1* 2) *  1 = ( 2 -  2) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
    -  2/ 1 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 2* 1 -  1* 2) *  1 = ( 2 -  2) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
    -  7/ 1 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 2* 1 -  1* 7) *  6 = ( 2 -  7) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
****4/1****
    -  4/ 1 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 4* 1 -  1* 4) *  1 = ( 4 -  4) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
    -  9/ 6 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 4* 6 -  1* 9) *  6 = ( 4 -  9) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
    -  4/ 6 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 4* 6 -  1* 4) *  1 = ( 4 -  4) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
    -  9/ 1 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 4* 1 -  1* 9) *  6 = ( 4 -  9) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
****6/1****
    -  6/ 1 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 6* 1 -  1* 6) *  1 = ( 6 -  6) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
    -  1/ 6 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 6* 6 -  1* 1) *  6 = ( 6 -  1) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
    -  1/ 1 (~  6) [mod 10]  |  ( 6* 1 -  1* 1) *  6 = ( 6 -  1) * 6 =  5 *  6 = 0
    -  6/ 6 (~  1) [mod 10]  |  ( 6* 6 -  1* 6) *  1 = ( 6 -  6) * 1 =  0 *  1 = 0
```

1. I find it exremely counter-intuitive that $0/1 \sim 5/6 ~(\operatorname{mod} 10)$. How should I think of the fraction $5/6$ becoming equal to $0$ when localizing at $6$, without trying to find an element $\alpha \in S$ such that $(6*0 + 5*1) \alpha = 0$. How can I "instantly see" which fractions are equivalent?
2. Similarly, I find it really counter intuitive that somehow, $3/1 = 8/1$ on performing this localization. What is actually "going on" here?
3. In general, giving $a/b$ and $c/d$ in $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ localized at $s_0$, how do we know if $a/b \sim c/d$ by "just looking", without having to cross multiply and find an element $\alpha \in S$ that kills of the cross ratio?
4. Even more generally, how do I gain an intuition for the general case in a ring $R$ with multiplicative subset $S$?

- [SAGE code to generate the above table](https://gist.github.com/bollu/2db693e31cd866aaec8b102eda0d7dcd)

Comment: You might expect some strange things to happen when you make a unit from a zero-divisor…

Comment: @Bernard yes, I'm trying to come to grips with precisely that :) If algebraic geometry / schemes help, I would gladly accept an answer which adopts that viewpoint. The  trouble I am having is precisely with zero divisors.

Comment: Possible help: Check out the example on Page 719 of Dummit & Foote's Abstract Algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Intuition behind localization is better understood with other kind of rings. If you think of $R[x,y]$ and perform the same constructions you would get better ideas. The key idea is that you are selecting which polinomial can get a multiplicative inverse (unlike it happens if you take the whole field of fractions). You can develop a lot of intuition of commutative algebra with the ring $R[x,y]$, thinking of "functions-polynomials" defined on the plane. Then, you can think of *ANY* ring (for example, your $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$) as functions defined in an special geometric object called *Scheme*, in this case, the spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$.

I recommend you the book: The geometry of Schemes, by Eisenbud and Harris.

Comment: I am aware of schemes and the geometric interpretation in $\mathbb C[x, y]$. The reason I feel that those are cheating is because they are domains [They lack zero divisors]. If we lack zero divisors, then we can simply embed the localization into the field of fractions. The real complication in $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$ is the existence of zero divisors. 

If you can expand on how the scheme theoretic view of elements of $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z$ as functions on the prime ideals gives intuition in this case, I'd love to understand.

Comment: Ok. I can interpret that thing, again like the case of usual functions. Indee, you have zero divisors in the ring of functions (piecewise functions, for example). The function represented by 5/6 is null in every point of its reduced domain, so it is equal 0.

Comment: That's dangerous reasoning and often untrue. Any nilpotent is zero at every prime ideal [because prime ideals contain all nilpotents] , but is not equal to zero. For example, consider the element $\epsilon$ of $\mathbb R[x]/(\epsilon^2)$. This element $\epsilon \neq 0$, but will be zero as a "function" on the scheme. So I don't believe the explanation given, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I don't know anything about schemes yet, but how about if we studied localizations of quotient of $\mathbb C[x,y]$ which are not domains? For example $\mathbb C[x,y]/(xy)$?